# ATG Endeca Commerce: Indexing failing at last mile crawl

Tags: indexing, atg, endeca

**The indexing is getting failed with the following error at the stage of EndecaScriptService**

The cas crawl is getting failed with a wierd socketTimeout exception which is quite random. Not sure whether this is because of the size of the data set that is getting indexed.

```
INFO: Starting baseline CAS crawl with id 'art-last-mile-crawl'.
Aug 02, 2017 11:18:44 AM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript
SEVERE: Error starting baseline crawl 'art-last-mile-crawl'.
Occurred while executing line 11 of valid BeanShell script:
[[

 8|      Dgidx.cleanDirs();
 9|
10|      // run crawl and archive any changes in dvalId mappings
11|      CAS.runBaselineCasCrawl("art-last-mile-crawl");
12|      CAS.archiveDvalIdMappingsForCrawlIfChanged("art-last-mile-crawl");
13|
14|      // archive logs and run the indexer

]]

Aug 02, 2017 11:18:44 AM com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller execute
SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'BaselineUpdate'. Releasing locks.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.invokeRequestedMethod(Controller.java:933)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.execute(Controller.java:271)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.Controller.main(Controller.java:138)
Caused by: com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException: Error executing valid BeanShell script.
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.runBeanShellScript(Script.java:180)
        at com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script.run(Script.java:127)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.CasCommunicationException: Error starting baseline crawl 'art-last-mile-crawl'.
        at com.endeca.eac.toolkit.component.cas.ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.startBaselineCasCrawl(ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.java:451)
        at com.endeca.eac.toolkit.component.cas.ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.runBaselineCasCrawl(ContentAcquisitionServerComponent.java:357)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at bsh.Reflect.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at bsh.Reflect.invokeObjectMethod(Unknown Source)
        at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(Unknown Source)
        at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
        at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
        at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:154)
        at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
        at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
        at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
```

Using ATG 11.2 & Endeca 11.2

Comment: Did you check if CAS is running or not?

Comment: @AjayAgrawal it was up and running. The problem is intermittent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the ATG Support Documentation:

> "httpSocketTimeout" is the maximum period of inactivity in milliseconds between two consecutive data packets before http times out. An in adequate value in this can cause the Read timed out error.
>
> By default the "httpSocketTimeout" is set to 60 secs. Increasing this resolves the read timeout error.

To fix this issue, edit the `/<app>/config/script/DataIngest.xml` in the deployed app to add `<property name="httpSocketTimeout" value="(some value)" />`

Your file will look something like this:

```
<property name="casHost" value="localhost" />
<property name="casPort" value="8500" />
<property name="httpSocketTimeout" value="180000" />
<property name="numPartialsBackups" value="5" />
```

You will need to experiment with the `httpSocketTimeout` until you no longer get the timeout. At some point you may need to increase it again.

Comment: can you help with some link for the ATG support documentation.. thanks

Comment: You need a login on the support site and may need an active support contract. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2042882.1